# uploading image into database using prime faces andhibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I want to upload the image using primefaces and hibernate but it is giving the following error when i did this example simple JDBC connection but i need it in Hibernate. When i tried it hibernate then it also need to covert when i tried this as given below then it is giving error. if any one have idea then please help

```
exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
    org.hibernate.type.BlobType.set(BlobType.java:49)
    org.hibernate.type.BlobType.nullSafeSet(BlobType.java:117)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1947)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1924)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$1.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2102)
    org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:32)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2108)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2588)
    org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
    org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:290)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:180)
    org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:108)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:186)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:175)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    com.school.entityDao.SchoolStudentDao.saveStudent(SchoolStudentDao.java:37)
    com.school.entity.SchoolStudent.saveStudent(SchoolStudent.java:381)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



The code i have done for the uploading for hibernate is

private UploadedFile file;

    private byte[] image;

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile image) {
        this.file = image;
    }





the above one is for the Managed bean and for saving is

public void saveStudent(SchoolStudent schoolStudent)
    {
        Transaction trans=null;
        Session session= HiberUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        File f=new File("C:\\Users\\Web It Experts\\Desktop\\New Instructions\\20.jpg");
        byte[] imageData=new byte[(int) f.length()];
        try{
            trans=session.beginTransaction();
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
            fileInputStream.read(imageData);
            fileInputStream.close();


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        schoolStudent.setImage(imageData);
        session.save(schoolStudent);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert byte array to java.sql.Blob. The example code show below.

```
import java.sql.Blob;
import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob;
...
byte[] imageData = .....;
try {
   Blob blob = new SerialBlob(imageData);
   schoolStudent.setImage(blob);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: then we don't need the code within try and catch block?
Just to convert into blob and then i think i have to save the same in blob type?
Please Explain...

Comment: @RohitKaushal "[B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob" ([B is a byte array), so you should convert to java.sql.Blob.

Comment: It works but do u have any idea how to convert UploadedFile to File so that i can give the component by selecting file from ui.

Comment: @RohitKaushal You can acheive by get InputStream from UploadedFile and put into DefaultStreamedContent. After that use <p:fileDownload value="#{file}" />, the file object is an object StreamedContent. However, you cannot convert UploadFile to java.io.File directly you should write to some path and then read it.

Comment: InputStream input=schoolStudent.getFile().getInputstream();
  DefaultStreamedContent d=new DefaultStreamedContent(input);

Ok i have done this.... Now how the input will be given to the java.io.File...

Comment: When you got StreamedContent file=new DefaultStreamedContent(input), you can use <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download #{fileBean.file}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowthichk-s"><p:fileDownload value="#{fileBean.file}" /></p:commandButton> in order to provide download that file. @RohitKaushal